# Manually order x-axis labels within each facet in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to manually reorder the x-axis labels within each facet.

The data are as follows:

```
df = structure(list(block = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), item = structure(c(14L, 
15L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
15L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
1L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L), .Label = c("p00e00d00", "p00e00d11", 
"p00e00d12", "p00e00d13", "p00e00d21", "p00e00d22", "p00e00d23", 
"p00e11d00", "p00e12d00", "p00e13d00", "p00e21d00", "p00e22d00", 
"p00e23d00", "p01e00d00", "p11e00d00", "p11e00d11", "p11e00d12", 
"p11e00d13", "p11e00d21", "p11e00d22", "p11e00d23", "p11e11d00", 
"p11e12d00", "p11e13d00", "p11e21d00", "p11e22d00", "p11e23d00", 
"p12e00d00", "p13e00d00", "p14e00d00", "p21e00d00", "p22e00d00"
), class = "factor"), response = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2", 
"1"), class = "factor"), n = c(345L, 511L, 583L, 613L, 612L, 
222L, 142L, 531L, 546L, 589L, 636L, 478L, 364L, 313L, 502L, 533L, 
587L, 603L, 385L, 298L, 263L, 518L, 546L, 563L, 593L, 435L, 351L, 
310L, 478L, 579L, 629L, 646L, 357L, 307L, 230L), freq = c(0.408284023668639, 
0.604733727810651, 0.689940828402367, 0.725443786982249, 0.724260355029586, 
0.262721893491124, 0.168047337278107, 0.628402366863905, 0.646153846153846, 
0.697041420118343, 0.752662721893491, 0.565680473372781, 0.430769230769231, 
0.370414201183432, 0.594082840236686, 0.630769230769231, 0.694674556213018, 
0.713609467455621, 0.455621301775148, 0.352662721893491, 0.311242603550296, 
0.61301775147929, 0.646153846153846, 0.666272189349112, 0.701775147928994, 
0.514792899408284, 0.415384615384615, 0.366863905325444, 0.565680473372781, 
0.685207100591716, 0.744378698224852, 0.764497041420118, 0.422485207100592, 
0.363313609467456, 0.272189349112426)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -35L), .Names = c("block", "item", 
"response", "n", "freq"))
```

There are five blocks, each block contains 7 items, and some items have the same names across blocks. I can therefore facet by block as follows:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = item, y = freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  facet_grid(.~block, scales = "free") + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1), expand = F) +  # need to add expanse = F to prevent zooming away 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1, vjust=1))
```

I also have vectors which states for each block the order that items should appear in. For example:

```
block_3_order = c("p11e13d00","p11e12d00", "p11e11d00", "p11e00d00", "p11e21d00", "p11e22d00","p11e23d00")
             )
block_4_order =  c("p00e00d13", "p00e00d12", "p00e00d11", "p00e00d00", "p00e00d21","p00e00d22","p00e00d23")
             )
```

I tried to reorder the "item" factor, but to get the desired effect I would need to split the dataframe into subsets representing blocks. Otherwise I am having trouble grasping how you can integrate the ordering of factors with the ggplot treatment of item as a single factor across facets.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a different custom axis order in each facet, you can create each "facet" as a separate plot and then lay them out together as if they were a single faceted plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
#devtools::install_github("baptiste/egg")
library(egg)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
theme_set(theme_bw())
```

First, create the custom orderings. The ones that are NULL will just be sorted alphabetically in the final plot.

```
b.order = list(b1 = NULL,
               b2 = NULL,
               b3 = c("p11e13d00","p11e12d00", "p11e11d00", "p11e00d00", "p11e21d00", "p11e22d00","p11e23d00"),
               b4 = c("p00e00d13", "p00e00d12", "p00e00d11", "p00e00d00", "p00e00d21","p00e00d22","p00e00d23"),
               b5 = NULL)
```

Create a list of plots, one for each `block`. We do this by splitting `df` by `block`. To get the custom ordering, we use `factor` to set the custom order based on the list `b.order`.

```
plist = map2(split(df, df$block), b.order,  
     ~ .x %>% group_by(block) %>% 
         mutate(item = factor(item, levels=if(is.null(.y)) sort(unique(item)) else .y)) %>%
       ggplot(aes(x = item, y = freq)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
        facet_grid(.~block, scales = "free") + 
        coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1), expand = F) +  # need to add expanse = F to prevent zooming away 
        scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1, vjust=1),
             plot.margin=margin(b=-5)) +
        labs(x=""))
```

Remove y-axis labels, title, and ticks from all but the left-most plot:

```
plist[2:length(plist)] = plist[2:length(plist)] %>% 
  map(~ .x + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                   axis.title.y=element_blank(),
                   axis.ticks.y=element_blank()))
```

Arrange the plots. We use `ggarrange` from the `egg` package in order to ensure that the plot panels all have the same horizontal width. We also need to add the `Item` label beneath the plot. However, `ggarrange` prints the plot to the output device, even inside `arrangeGrob`. So we create the object `p`, clear the device and then redraw the final plot.

```
p = arrangeGrob(ggarrange(plots=plist, ncol=length(plist)),
                textGrob("Item"), heights=c(20,1))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(p)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and I really appreciate the tips on removing all but the leftmost axis and ggarrange. Thanks!